# connect to localhost on iPhone over Wifi not working

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using iPhone5 and want to connect to my localhost on my local server via wifi but keep not being able to do so. I have read many blogs and all options i have exhausted. Dont know if someone else has any other option out there. The options i have exhausted so far are:

1. Use my ip address - it notices it but always throw a 401 error basically my ip address is 192.168.0.10 but when i call that via my iphone it calls 192.168.0.6 instead dont know why. I hv tried calling that instead but it doesnt work
2. Use ur computer name.local - I have tried this but it doesnt work
3. Turn-off ur firewall. I have also done this but it also doesnt work still
4. Use a different port. I have started my server on another port e.g. 3002 and called from my iphone 192.168.0.10:3002 still doesnt work.

Can anyone let me know what else to do?

thanks

Comment: "localhost" always refers to the device on which it is given - never some other device. You may want to reword your question now.

Comment: post your code of the calling part, i.e. the url and how you call it.

Comment: You could try installing a 3rd party app that can ping a given host. That way you can troubleshoot the connection problem without involving any of your code.

Comment: @ama1111 yah i ended up using tunnels